# map_sync using an array as argument

Tags: parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I would like to map_sync a function using an array as argument.

I obtain an error "TypeError: cannot pickle 'memoryview' object" when I run this simple code (I already have ipyparallel engines running):

```
cl = ipp.Client("./profile_aaaa/security/ipcontroller-client.json")
dview = cl[:]


def myf(i,E):
  return i,E

def main_function():
  E=numpy.ones(210)  # if E is array error "TypeError: cannot pickle 'memoryview' object"
  # E=3  # if E not an array it works
  f_calculate=lambda i: myf(i,E)
  results=dview.map_sync(f_calculate,numpy.arange(10)) 
  return 0

dview["myf"]=myf
main_function()
```

The error is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[920], line 12
      9   return 0
     11 dview["myf"]=myf
---> 12 main_function()

Cell In[920], line 8, in main_function()
      6 # E=3  # if E not array it works
      7 f_calculate=lambda i: myf(i,E)
----> 8 results=dview.map_sync(f_calculate,numpy.arange(10)) 
      9 return 0
....
....
....

--> 125 buffers.insert(0, pickle.dumps(cobj, PICKLE_PROTOCOL))
    126 return buffers

TypeError: cannot pickle 'memoryview' object
```

Probably related to the fact that numpy arrays cannot be pickled when passing as argument. I am stuck..
Thank you !